# 301 dynamic redirects not correct working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I need to change old dynamic urls to new, so I have created .htaccess file, but something wrong and redirect to `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` problem.

Below my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^movie/(.+)/$ /cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat\.php$ /movie/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the original URI, and redirect to the pretty URL from that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /cat\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat\.php$ /movie/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^movie/(.+)/$ /cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have another one question, if I add additional dymanic url like 
cat.php?do=pc&search="dynamic get"?